# How can I edit the name of a file (that will be downloaded) via php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, submit, download, file-rename

I am trying to make a script that will rename a file based off what a user submitted in a textbox and download it (I do not want it to affect other people's downloads though, so I want the name of the file to only be based off what they submitted ). I do not know much Javascript and am not sure if I would use php or javscript to edit it. Also I have no clue how I would do it. Any help?

Comment: add a download attrib to a normal <a> tag to specify a filename and force a download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like so:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';
$new_file_name='monkey_'.$_POST['colour'].'.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$new_file_name);
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```